# How to `\input` a tex file from URL in LaTeX?

Tags: latex

In Latex, we could often write a section in a separate `.tex` file, and in the main file to import it by calling `\input{*.tex}`

However, if the tex file is online with some URL, how could we use

`\input{https://somewebsite/file.tex}`

Comment: Download it on you batchfile / makefile that build the document and process it as a local file. Latex is already slow, do not slow down it further.

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot: it's got to be a local file.

Comment: Possible with context: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54955/36296

Answer (score 0):

Use lualatex

```
%!TEX TS-program = lualatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% give lualatex --shell-escape
\immediate\write18{biber \jobname}

\input{|"curl --stderr /dev/null -L https://docs.google.com/document/d/1xxxxxxxXlQ/export?format=txt"}
```

% the URL has been invalidated